# Genetic condition that leaves open gaps between teeth?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

You would think this would be something a dentist knows.  I've asked scores of dentists this very question and no one has an answer.  It's got to have a name.

It's fairly common.  The teeth don't touch the ones adjacent.  There's a tooth and then an open half space and then another tooth and so on.  The whole mouth is like this.  LOL  I'm sure there MUST be a name for this.  I've been trying to find the name for this for more than 20 years.

Comment: I've heard/read "gap-toothed" a few times.

Comment: Time to find a new dentist...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a medical term and is not a question about the nuts and bolts of the English language.

Comment: You have an answer, but this is not the right Stack Exchange site for this question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I very strongly disagree with that. Nowhere does the question mention anything about medical terms. The fact that the only answer given so far is of a medical natural doesn’t mean that the asker isn’t simply asking for a commonly used English term to describe this commonly occurring phenomenon. If the question had been about what you call it when someone’s knees are further apart than their feet, an answer could be either _bowleggedness/bandiness_ or _genu varum/tibia vara_. One is clearly medical, but the other is quite on-topic for ELU.

Comment: The purpose of the study was to estimate familial correlations and heritability to evaluate familial aggregation patterns of maxillary midline diastemas.  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12532061

Comment: The article linked to by Jim contains: _by JR Gass - ‎2003 - ‎Cited by 36 - ‎Related articles
The preliminary results suggest a possible genetic basis for maxillary midline diastema_. Since it was published in 2003, it is quite possible that it has not yet been established that such diastema is due to a genetic condition. In which case it is no wonder there is no term for the possibly non-existent condition.

Comment: @AndrewLeach What's wrong with asking for a medical term? There's no medicalenglish.SE

Answer (score 3):

[Diastema](https://www.google.com/search?q=Diastema%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=Diastema) -Google

> A diastema is a space or gap between two teeth. It appears most often between the two upper front teeth. However, gaps can occur between any two teeth. -[Colgate](http://www.colgate.com/app/CP/US/EN/OC/Information/Articles/Cosmetic-Dentistry/Orthodontics/Orthodontic-Basics/article/Diastema-Gap-Between-Teeth.cvsp)

Comment: Note that a diastema is the space or gap between teeth, but the OP asks for the name of a genetic condition that causes diastemas.

Comment: @jim it's called being an offspring? I don't think it's a genetic condition, it's just your genetics. It's what happens when you get your dad's jaw and your mom's teeth (or so my Dentist said).

Comment: @Mazura  ...and what's wrong with writing in the first person?  I saw your page and don't know another way to ask a question on this forum.  Or should I say, "One saw your page... ".  LOL

Comment: @AllisonHunt I try to keep it impersonal. Instead of saying *you* messed it up because of X, say *it* is messed up because of X. I suppose I should say avoid the use of first person pronouns.